# How can regex ignore escaped-quotes when matching strings?

Tags: regex, escaping, negative-lookbehind

I'm trying to write a regex that will match everything BUT an apostrophe that has not been escaped.  Consider the following:

```
<?php $s = 'Hi everyone, we\'re ready now.'; ?>
```

My goal is to write a regular expression that will essentially match the string portion of that. I'm thinking of something such as

```
/.*'([^']).*/
```

in order to match a simple string, but I've been trying to figure out how to get a negative lookbehind working on that apostrophe to ensure that it is not preceded by a backslash...

Any ideas?

- JMT

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
$backslash = '\\';

$pattern = <<< PATTERN
#(["'])(?:{$backslash}{$backslash}?+.)*?{$backslash}1#
PATTERN;

foreach(array(
    "<?php \$s = 'Hi everyone, we\\'re ready now.'; ?>",
    '<?php $s = "Hi everyone, we\\"re ready now."; ?>',
    "xyz'a\\'bc\\d'123",
    "x = 'My string ends with with a backslash\\\\';"
    ) as $subject) {
        preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches);
        echo $subject , ' => ', $matches[0], "\n\n";
}
```

prints

```
<?php $s = 'Hi everyone, we\'re ready now.'; ?> => 'Hi everyone, we\'re ready now.'

<?php $s = "Hi everyone, we\"re ready now."; ?> => "Hi everyone, we\"re ready now."

xyz'a\'bc\d'123 => 'a\'bc\d'

x = 'My string ends with with a backslash\\'; => 'My string ends with with a backslash\\'
```

Comment: Voting up because you provided test cases.

Answer (score 4):

Here's my solution with test cases:

```
/.*?'((?:\\\\|\\'|[^'])*+)'/
```

And my (Perl, but I don't use any Perl-specific features I don't think) proof:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %tests = ();
$tests{'Case 1'} = <<'EOF';
$var = 'My string';
EOF

$tests{'Case 2'} = <<'EOF';
$var = 'My string has it\'s challenges';
EOF

$tests{'Case 3'} = <<'EOF';
$var = 'My string ends with a backslash\\';
EOF

foreach my $key (sort (keys %tests)) {
    print "$key...\n";
    if ($tests{$key} =~ m/.*?'((?:\\\\|\\'|[^'])*+)'/) {
        print " ... '$1'\n";
    } else {
        print " ... NO MATCH\n";
    }
}
```

Running this shows:

```
$ perl a.pl
Case 1...
 ... 'My string'
Case 2...
 ... 'My string has it\'s challenges'
Case 3...
 ... 'My string ends with a backslash\\'
```

Note that the initial wildcard at the start needs to be non-greedy.  Then I use non-backtracking matches to gobble up \\ and \' and then anything else that is not a standalone quote character.

I think this one probably mimics the compiler's built-in approach, which should make it pretty bullet-proof.

Answer (score 2):

```
/.*'([^'\\]|\\.)*'.*/
```

The parenthesized portion looks for non-apostrophes/backslashes and backslash-escaped characters. If only certain characters can be escaped change the `\\.` to `\\['\\a-z]`, or whatever.

Comment: Very nearly, but that doesn't handle the pathological case...
'My string ends with with a backslash\\'

Comment: Thanks John! Fortunately for me, the cases I'm going to have to deal with can be restrained, and will never reach the problem that the.jxc describes. Very simple solution, of which I really should have thought. Again, thank you! : )

Answer (score 0):

```
Regex reg = new Regex("(?<!\\\\)'(?<string>.*?)(?<!\\\\)'");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is for JavaScript:

`/('|")(?:\\\\|\\\1|[\s\S])*?\1/`

it...

- matches single or double quoted strings
- matches empty strings (length 0)
- matches strings with embedded whitespace (`\n`, `\t`, etc.)
- skips inner escaped quotes (single or double)
- skips single quotes within double quotes and vice versa

Only the first quote is captured. You can capture the unquoted string in $2 with:

`/('|")((?:\\\\|\\\1|[\s\S])*?)\1/`