# Regex: match everything but escaped characters

Tags: python, regex, scrapy, escaping

I am using scrapy to scrape the date that a comment was posted on a forum. I have been able to scrape the contents of the divider that contains the date, but it has escaped characters on both sides that make the string unusable. I need to create a regex expression which matches everything except for escaped characters.

The string I am working with is `"\r\n\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t08-07-2019, 11:37:16 AM\r\n\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t"`. I want only to match the date inside.

The pattern that I was trying to use was `(?<!\\\\)\\+[\\w-]+`, as was recommended by other topics, but this doesn't match anything in that string.

Comment: Perhaps match a "date like" pattern instead. `[\\w-]+` is a broad match and will not match  `,` space or `:`

Comment: `/('|")((?:\\\\|\\\1|[\s\S])*?)\1/`

  check  this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/31181803/6923146

Comment: hmm, doesn't work as far as I can tell, thanks for the reference to the other topic though

Comment: If you want to match a single backslash followed by a single word character you could use `(?<!\\)\\\w` https://regex101.com/r/N3H5BY/1 Then replace the matches with an empty strings to leave the date and time.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm very new to regex and don't know how to replace the matches with empty strings. Could you give an example?

Comment: What is the language or tool?

Comment: scrapy, so python

Comment: If the tabs and newlines are real tabs and newlines in the string so not literally `\n` then you could replace them like this using just a character class  `[\r\n\t]+` https://ideone.com/ZxR8hC or else use https://ideone.com/0st8cU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need regex if you want to match **everything**. I strongly recommend you to use [Item Loaders](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html) in Scrapy to process your fields (using `.strip()` etc).

Also you can remove unwanted characters from your string using XPath `normalize-space()`:

```
event_time = response.xpath('normalize-space(string(//YOUR/XPATH/HERE))').get()
```

But if you want to match **part** of a complex string you can use regular expresssion of course:

```
event_time = response.xpath('//YOUR/XPATH/HERE').re_first(r'(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4},\s+\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\s+\w{2})')
```